# How TO Dispaly Default Message in Marquee

Tags: java

I am using marquee in jsp page. Displaying some data using Ajax. Now i want to display some default message when data is not available in database, and the Default message is not rotating

please give me Solution.

Comment: *"I am using marquee"*  God help your visitors.  Do you intend to round that out with brightly colored animated GIFs that have an animation rate that will induce photo-sensitive epileptic fits, pornographer colors (light text on dark BG), text in ALL CAPS with one primary color per paragraph, Verdana font, and more animated GIFs that 'jiggle' proclaiming 'YOU ARE OUR MILLIONTH VISITOR, CLICK HERE TO COLLECT YOUR PRIZE'?  I (and millions of others) were glad to see the death of the original Marquee element.  Please don't resurrect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<marquee style="height:10;width:100" scrollamount="100" scrolldelay="500">hello world</marquee>`

Comment: how to stop that continuous rotation  of default  text when no data is there..i want to show only default message in that..when my ajax cal return null data from data base??